# how to Optimize multiple searches in the table

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to select a few fields from the table and search For example, a user records the project name, color project status, project date, and so on
For example, in the search form, I want to select the project name and color of the project status and project date, and fetch the information
But the problem is that I have to apply too many (if)
How can I select and search multiple fields with the least if ?
Please see the image and the codes and help.

[image]

```
        if (hesabrsee.Projectid != 0 && red != 0 && yealoo != 0)
        {

            fraindList = fraindList.Where(p => p.Projectid == hesabrsee.Projectid && p.ControlState == red && p.ControlState == yealoo);
            ViewBag.yealoo = "checked";
            ViewBag.red = "checked";
            return View(fraindList.ToList());
        }

            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">

                <label>نام پروژه</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="form_frame" name="Projectid">

                    <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.proList)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.projectID">@item.projectName</option>

                    }

                </select>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following code:

```
string s = "select * from Hesabrsee where Projectid=" + hesabrsee.Projectid;
            s += red != 0 ? "ControlState==red" : "";
            s += green != 0 ? "ControlState==green" : "";
            var fraindList = _context.Student.FromSqlRaw(s).AsEnumerable();
            if (FramDate != null)
            {
                fraindList = fraindList.Where(l => l.ControlDate.Date >= ConvertDateTime.ConvertShamsiToMiladi(FramDate));
            }
            if (ToDate != null)
            {
                fraindList = fraindList.Where(l => l.ControlDate.Date >= ConvertDateTime.ConvertShamsiToMiladi(ToDate));
            }

            return View(fraindList.ToList());
```

Comment: I edited the question code.Now I have two problems. The first is in the if condition, I can not give two different values to one variable.In this example I said that if the status control is red and green the condition is applied (the type of status control is int) but in the condition it takes only one value

Comment: Second, when I select the project name from the dropdown and the information is fetched and the page is refreshed, the dropdown information is returned by default. I want the selected item to remain after the refresh of the page.